# Blazor - Binding data without using any event (onChange, onInput ...)

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

We have to update data to the Model in an action (like save).
Our idea: Do not want to make server call often for every time the "focus looses" from the HTML element. Finally we want to update the value while Submit.

```
<div>
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" value="@student.Name" />
    <br />
    <label>Age</label>
    <input type="text" value="@student.Age" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" @onclick="Save" />
</div>

@code {
    Student student = new Student();

    private void Save()
    {
        // At this stage - the value should be updated to the model.
    } 
}
```

Comment: Use blazor wasm, or a bunch of javascript and JS interopt

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried updating Visual Studio and .Net Framework Core? Because since I did that it is doing what you asked automatically, saving the data every time an input text loses focus, I don't know why, if it's a bug or a default feature.
[A video I did showcasing this issue](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RXFqEgIFPE). You can see on the code I did nothing to make this happen.

Comment: actually i don't want to save the data every time textbox loses focus.